# Increasing Slugsize on Heroku

Tags: heroku

Heroku is imposing [300MB limit on slugsize](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#slug-size). Normally, this should be way more than enough for most of the web apps. However, our company uses libraries that are frequently 50MB or more each, and there are a lot of those.

Is there anyway to increase the slug size limit on Heroku? Has anyone had any success with overcoming this limit?

Answer (score 0):

Reading a bit from the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler), it seems that it is not something Heroku does. The limitation is related to their expectations of storage consumed per application and circumventing it may result in malfunctioning services. In case they consider it a contract breach, they may take down your service. So I would not advise trying really hard. The documentation tells that smaller slugs will deploy faster and your question is directly against it.

Comment: I was able to bring it down to 300MB.. However, I'm not sure what you mean by "not something Heroku does"? It's clearly a limitation by Heroku. Sure, it may be to keep their service in good health, but still Heroku. And it's not like there's a way to go around it.. if slug size grows over 300MB, Heroku simply doesn't let you put it on a dyno. (as far as I know. Hence this question. Just wondered if there was a way to increase it.)

Comment: We can increase it yes on a per app basis, but it has an impact on deployment speed and scaling time as it takes longer to copy the slug form S3. We would always encourage you to keep the slug as trimmed as possible and use a `.slugignore` to stop files from making it into the slug.